# Get interface to Resolve unity container

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, interface, unity-container

How can i pass string to unity container to resolve interface because i don't know the interface i need to resolve each time if it will be IFoo or IBar
for example

```
interface IParentInterface{
string GetData();
}
interface IFoo:IParentInterface{}
interface IBar:IParentInterface{}
class FooService : IFoo{
string GetData(){}
}
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
string serviceName="IFoo";
IParentInterface parentInterfaceObj= container.Resolve<serviceName>();
```

So,in this case if i pass "IFoo" as string to container then it will resolve IFoo interface.

Comment: What is `IFoo` for? Why do you not register two implementations of `IParentInterface`?

Comment: IFoo is an interface for Foo Service , all what i want to do once client pass name of interface as string then resolve required interface with it's service class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the non-generic version of `Resolve` and pass it a type instance.You can create the type from an assembly-qualified type name, for example:

```
var instance = container.Resolve(Type.Get("System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"));
```

I'd recommend using named registrations, though, because you can define your own, shorter identifiers.

```
container.Register<IService, SuperFoo>( "foo" );
var instance = container.Resolve<IService>( "foo" );
```